# Mirror team foundation server 2015 git repo to bitbucket

Tags: git, tfs, push, bitbucket, mirror

I have a tfs 2015 server with a git repo. When a developer carries out a sync, I would like tfs to also push the changes to bitbucket git repo.

Can anyone suggest any solution to this?

Comment: What do you mean by "When developer carries out a sync"?

Comment: From what I understand, visual studio will commit to the local git, after which the commit needs to be synced with tfs. Basically a sync is a push to the tfs git repo.

Comment: So you were asking if there is a commit in the local, the tfs has to push that change to the remote without an extra step

Comment: What I need is tfs to push the changes to bitbucket or a remote repo in the event where tfs receives a commit/push.

Comment: I suggest you read the following  before using GIT. http://incyclesoftware.com/2014/03/using-git-team-foundation-server-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: Thanks Vamsi but the article you sent is more about using visual studio with git than tfs and git. Nevertheless thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

TFS supports integrate with Bitbucket, you can either push a commit to BitBucket, or to TFS, but you can't push them togther.

Go to Team Explorer--select Git project, click Settings--Repository Settings--Remotes--Add Remote, when you push the commit, you can select the Remote you want to push.

Comment: Thank you Cece. But, from my understanding, this configuration needs to be done on each vs 2015 workstation right? If one of the devs do not add this configuration, his work won't be pushed to bitbucket. I am looking for a server side solution rather.

Comment: I'm afraid your requirement can't be achieved by default IDE, you may need to develop your own script to push commits to both TFS and BitBucket, and force your team to use the script too.